# Reusing other entity's view

Tags: spring-mvc, view, spring-roo

I have 2 entities in my Spring Roo application, `Experiment` and `Story`. `Experiment` can contain several stories. I have already build a view for displaying a story.

Can I directly reuse that view to render the stories that are contained in an experiment's view? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a shot-in-the-dark, but I would say you could do something using JSP tags that look at some value, check the class type, and switch between displaying one Story or a list of Stories.

Or, instead of that, you could make your Model value always be a List, and then just make your view JSP always loop the list, so if it gets a list of 1, it shows 1, a list of 10 would show the 10.

Or, you could create a custom Dojo Widget.  Have separate view (or do the above) and simply use the custom widget to display a single Story.  Loop through the list, adding additional Widgets, you get a display of more than one.